# Quorum node address

Tags: web3j, quorum, enode

In the Node class of the Quorum Web3j. The String address what is?

```
package org.web3j.quorum;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Quorum node configuration class.
 */
public class Node {

private final String address;
private final List<String> publicKeys;
private final String url;
```

A particular node has an address? And how can I get that address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not well-acquainted with web3j.quorum, so possibly a kind spirit will chime in if this is off. If I'm not mistaken, those would be the `enode` addresses for the nodes.

In Ethereum and Quorom, nodes have an "enode address" which is a unique identifier. Have a look at this:

```
[
  "enode://ac6b1096ca56b9f6d004b779ae3728bf83f8e22453404cc3cef16a3d9b96608bc67c4b30db88e0a5a6c6390213f7acbe1153ff6d23ce57380104288ae19373ef@127.0.0.1:21000?discport=0&raftport=50401",
  "enode://0ba6b9f606a43a95edc6247cdb1c1e105145817be7bcafd6b2c0ba15d58145f0dc1a194f70ba73cd6f4cdd6864edc7687f311254c7555cc32e4d45aeb1b80416@127.0.0.1:21001?discport=0&raftport=50402",
  "enode://579f786d4e2830bbcc02815a27e8a9bacccc9605df4dc6f20bcc1a6eb391e7225fff7cb83e5b4ecd1f3a94d8b733803f2f66b7e871961e7b029e22c155c3a778@127.0.0.1:21002?discport=0&raftport=50403",
  "enode://3d9ca5956b38557aba991e31cf510d4df641dce9cc26bfeb7de082f0c07abb6ede3a58410c8f249dabeecee4ad3979929ac4c7c496ad20b8cfdd061b7401b4f5@127.0.0.1:21003?discport=0&raftport=50404",
  "enode://3701f007bfa4cb26512d7df18e6bbd202e8484a6e11d387af6e482b525fa25542d46ff9c99db87bd419b980c24a086117a397f6d8f88e74351b41693880ea0cb@127.0.0.1:21004?discport=0&raftport=50405",
  "enode://eacaa74c4b0e7a9e12d2fe5fee6595eda841d6d992c35dbbcc50fcee4aa86dfbbdeff7dc7e72c2305d5a62257f82737a8cffc80474c15c611c037f52db1a3a7b@127.0.0.1:21005?discport=0&raftport=50406",
  "enode://239c1f044a2b03b6c4713109af036b775c5418fe4ca63b04b1ce00124af00ddab7cc088fc46020cdc783b6207efe624551be4c06a994993d8d70f684688fb7cf@127.0.0.1:21006?discport=0&raftport=50407"
]
```

From the 7 nodes example: https://github.com/jpmorganchase/quorum-examples/blob/master/examples/7nodes/permissioned-nodes.json

You can see that's describing a network topology where the nodes are known by these identifiers. As a side note, the same concept exists in Ethereum. You can see it in network discovery, the bootstrap nodes, admin.addPeer(), and similar topics.

Hope it helps.

Comment: According to this example. https://github.com/web3j/quorum/blob/master/src/test/java/org/web3j/quorum/QuorumIT.java It seems that the address is one user address. But I can´t confirm yet because developing my code I still can´t create a great ClienTransactionManager to deploy my contracts. Im trying to fix and improve the code. When I solve the code I will post the answer to future readers. Thankyou  for your always complete and helpfull answes @Rob